# #1054 - Unknown column inner join and update order by

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables: 
items and stock. 
items has all the information about all the product descriptions and stock, while tbl_stock are the stock are saved. I want to update a column av_stock in tbl stock.
Here are my query :

```
update `stock` inner JOIN
(
   SELECT item_total_stock FROM items 
   ORDER BY item_total_stock DESC
) s
ON items.id = stock.id
set stock.av_stock = `item_total_stock`
```

But i received error

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'items.id' in 'on clause'
```

I've check the table is correct and also the id is correct, any clue?

Answer (score 2):

The alias you use in the join has to match the subquery:

```
UPDATE stock s
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT item_total_stock
    FROM items 
) i
    ON i.id = s.id
SET av_stock = item_total_stock
```

But, you don't even need a subquery here:

```
UPDATE stock s
INNER JOIN items i
    ON i.id = s.id
SET av_stock = i.item_total_stock
```

Answer (score 0):

In your inner join sql should have column `id`

```
update `stock` a inner JOIN
(
   SELECT id,item_total_stock FROM items 
   ORDER BY item_total_stock DESC
) s
ON s.id = a.id
set a.av_stock = s.`item_total_stock`
```